# How to read image source or image name in xamarin.forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I am working on Xamarin forms, where I have used TapGestureRecognizer inside image now on tap of that image I need to get the source of the image in c#. How do I get that?. Why I am doing this is, radio buttons are not available in Xamarin forms, On tap of the image I will check the source of the image if the source is checked image then I need to change the source to unchecked and vice versa.

Here is my XAML code

```
   <Image  Scale="0.7"  HorizontalOptions="Start" x:Name="radioButton" Source="unchecked.png">
       <Image.GestureRecognizers>
           <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="radioButton_Clicked"> 
           </TapGestureRecognizer>
       </Image.GestureRecognizers>
   </Image>
```

Here is my C# code

```
    private void radioButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var imageSource = "";//get image source here
        if (imageSource == "Checked.png")
        {
            radioButton.Source = "Unchecked.png";
        }
        else
        {
            radioButton.Source = "Checked.png";
        }
    }
```

Comment: you can do like this      var image = (Image)sender;
            var selectedImage = image.Source as FileImageSource;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can achieve like this on radioButton_Clicked action

```
 private void radioButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var imageSource = (Image)sender;//get image source here
    var selectedImage = imageSource.Source as FileImageSource;

    if (selectedImage.File == "Checked.png")
    {
        radioButton.Source = "Unchecked.png";
    }
    else
    {
        radioButton.Source = "Checked.png";
    }
}
```

or you can use the custom plugin for support checked box refer this
https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs

Comment: I want to upvote your answer but i dont have repuations to upvote

Comment: @SagarPatil its okey

Answer (score 0):

you can cast sender to image control

```
var imageSender = (Image)sender;
```

[gestures](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/gestures/tap)

Comment: If i use var imageSender = (Image)sender; i can get imageSender.Source but file name resides under imageSender.Source.File . How can get that?